# Folder contains invisible file whose name starts with ..\..\

Tags: macos, filesystem, symlink, invisible-files

I have a Visual Studio for Mac project folder that contains an unusual file: The file is only visible with `ls -A` in the terminal, and its name is `..\..\items.json`:

```
~/Projects/Boss/Boss/bin/Debug % ls -A
..\..\items.json        .DS_Store
~/Projects/Boss/Boss/bin/Debug %
```

(I understand what the file is, and where it originally came from - so the file name or contents of the file aren't the problem. The fact that it's invisible and its name begins with `..\..\` is the problem.)

I want to delete this file. As a first attempt, I moved everything else in the folder to somewhere else and then deleted the folder. Then I re-created the folder and the file was immediately present again!

How can I delete it?

Comment: Can you delete it in the Finder, if you show hidden files with Command Shift period?

Comment: It isn't displayed in the Finder when I press Command Shift period.

Comment: Are you saying that after recreation of the folder with `mkdir Debug` (and no other action) the "..\..\items.json" file is present in that folder?

Comment: Can you use wildcards to delete "something something, items.json"...?  Clearly that's a "Windows" style of filepath. Might anything in Visual Studio have generated this file?

Comment: @MartinR - I re-created the folder in the Finder (via the File menu), and then checked with ls -A in the terminal, and the file was still present.
However, the file isn't there now! I'm not sure what has changed, but it's gone. Even after making a debug build in Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac, the file isn't there any more. I should probably close this question somehow...

Comment: Better would be to make an answer with what you saw and what version of macOS and VS Code were in play. I’m sure someone else may need this in a year or two

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -i —- ./*items.json
```

should expand correctly and prompt you to confirm the deletion.